# RX2.0 nested subscription error handling

Tags: error-handling, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm trying to figure out how exceptions are caught by RX streams. In particular, if I have a subscription within a subscription and the inner subscription receives an exception from it's observable, do I need to handle that in onError for inner subscription or can I handle it in onError of parent subscription?

```
observableThing1.subscribe({ _ ->
    observableThing2.subscribe({ _ ->
        // Something horrible happens here an an exception is throw by observableThing2
    })
}, { error -> 
    // Expecting I can handle all errors at the top most subscription
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you'd need to handle `onError` for every `subscription`:

```
    observable1Thing().subscribe({ obs1Result -> 

        observable2Thing().subscribe({ obs2Result -> 

        }, { obs2Error -> 

        })


    }, { obs1error -> 

    })
```

If you'd combine the `observables` with an operator like `flatMap`, you'd only need one `subcription` and thus handle only one `onError` case. 
Which operator you would use depends on how you want to combine the `observables`.

Example:

```
    obs1().flatMap { obs2() }.subscribe({

    }, { error ->

    })
```

Comment: This isn't very useful for those cases where each observable really needs to handle their own errors separately.